# Calling onClick outside of a component acting globally

Tags: reactjs

so i have this definition here:

```
const generateList = props => {
...
    item = <ListItemEl
          icon='directions'
          text={'Directions'}
          onClick={props.openGoogleMaps(coords)}
        />
...
}

const SideList = props => {
  const listItems = generateList(props)

  return (
    <List>
      {listItems}
    </List>
  )
}
```

however the onClick action is not bound to that specific ListItemEl.

The onClick is called way up the component tree that this ListItemEl belongs to.

openGoogleMaps is successfully called but upon clicking anything not just that ListItemEl.

here is the parent component when openGoogleMaps is passed.

```
    class index extends Component {

      openGoogleMaps(coords) {
        const center = PolygonCenter(coords)
        window.open(
          "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=" +
            center.coordinates[0] +
            "," +
            center.coordinates[1]
        )
      }

    ...

      {context.state.drawerOpen ? <SideList data={this.props.data} openGoogleMaps={this.openGoogleMaps}/> : null} 
}
```

i'm guessing this has something to do with binding openGoogleMaps to that specific ListItemEl but when i try to do that with 'this.props.openGoogleMaps(coords).bind(this)'
or something similar the onClick no longer works anywhere.

also im guessing this has to do with a gap in my knowledge concerning defining 'const' vs a component. previously when i've used bind i've used 'this' in front of the function im binding but since the ListItemEl is defined in a const i can't use
'this'. please and thank you

also here is the branch, repo and file where the problem is occuring https://github.com/CodeForCary/cary-connects-web/blob/googlemaps/src/components/Drawer/SideList.js

Comment: Have you tried writing `onClick={() => props.openGoogleMaps(coords)}` instead? `onClick={props.openGoogleMaps(coords)}` invokes the `props.openGoogleMaps` function directly on render.

Comment: yeah that just removes any onclick action at all. I do get this error upon clicking a parent component Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `SideList`.

Comment: It's not an error but a warning. To fix the warning You need to set unique id to SideList when calling here {context.state.drawerOpen ? <SideList id={"some unique id"} ....